# Mongoose's static method throwing: TypeError: Model.call has no method 'save'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I send a completely valid JSON body across a route in Express, I get the following error related to a static method of a model in Mongoose.

```
Product.save({
        ^
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId){
bla bla bla ...
} has no method 'save'
```

I have the following routing function in Express:

```
function createNewProduct(req, res){
    // Check if the Merchant is authorized
    User.checkIfExists(req.body.key, function(isThere, user){
        // Check if username is valid
        if(isThere === true){
            // Check if he has merchant priveleges
            if(user.usertype == 'merchant'){
                // Check if all the product field are valid
                // TODO add a product parameter validator here

                // Generate a OriginID
                var originId = user.username + Date.now();

                // Save the product to the db
                Product.createNewProduct(originId, req.body, function(isItCreated, product){
                    if(isItCreated === true){
                        res.json(product);
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            "error":"Problem in database!"
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    "error": "Not A Merchant"
                });
            }
        } else {
            res.json({
                "error": "Invalid Username"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Following is the implementation of createNewProduct static in Mongoose:

```
// Static method for creating a product
productSchema.static('createNewProduct', function(originId, reqBody, callback){
    Product.save({
        "originId": originId,
        "name": reqBody.name,
        //image: { type: String },
        "merchant": reqBody.key,
        //shop: String,
        "description": reqBody.description,
        "cost": reqBody.cost,
        "availableNow": true
    }, function(err, product){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error creating new product');
            console.log(err);
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true, product);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK - That worked, thanks! But I have another set-up where I am using save method on Mongoose model inside a Mongoose static method on same model and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) is an instance method, so you can only call it on a `Product` model instance, not the model itself.

To create a new document based on the `Product` model and save it, call [`create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) on the model instead:

```
Product.create({...}, function(err, product) {...});
```

Alternatively, you could separately create a new `Product` model instance and then call `save` on *that*:

```
var product = new Product({...});
product.save(function(err, product) {...});
```